# Font Awesome unicodes displaying as text

Tags: css, unicode, font-awesome

I'm trying to insert a `FontAwesome` icon via css using the Unicode, and my page is displaying it as text. So if the Unicode for a house icon is f015, my browser is displaying "/f015" instead of displaying a house icon.

HTML header includes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

CSS:

```
#MenuBarLink1 a:before {
      position: absolute;
      left: 1em;
      padding: 0 1px;
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      content: "/f015";
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
      transform: translateZ(0);
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
      transition-duration: 0.1s;
      -webkit-transition-property: transform;
      transition-property: transform;
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
      transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
```

I'm wondering if I need to do anything to declare the font-family besides simply including that link in my HTML header. I have downloaded all the Font Awesome files, but I am only using the online link because I read that was better.

Thanks for helping a newb! :)

Comment: Are you developing locally (file://) ?

Comment: Do you have the character set set to utf-8?

Comment: I am developing locally, and yes my header includes meta charset utf-8
The icons work perfect when I put them in html (fa fa-home) but haven't gotten them to work via css yet.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong slash. use content : '\f015';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong slash. Use,

```
content : '\f015';
```

Comment: You were right. And I feel very silly. Unfortunately, now with the correct slash, I'm only getting a hollow box, not the actual icon. Tried with a couple different codes now. I'll try to answer this on my own, but if you know, that'd be so helpful also.

Comment: Fixed it by adding a link to my local FontAwesome files rather than just the link to the online source. Is this because I am developing locally?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got that online source directly from the Font Awesome site. Why wouldn't they include the "http:" in their source code that they advise you to copy? Weird....